# Table: making a table cause the blank page

Tags: tables, pdftex

I made a simple table, but I found that it cause the text move down and leave a large space. Why is that? Could any one tell me how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ l  | l }
    \hline
    Symbols& Description\\ \hline
    N& The number of SNPs \\ \hline
    n& The number of patients \\ \hline
   X_i&$i$th SNP \\ \hline
   Y&the endpoint  \\\hline
   \beta_i&Effect size for$i$th SNP   \\\hline
   p_{i+}&The probability $X_i=1$ given $Y =+1$ \\\hline
   p_{i-}&The probability $X_i=1 $given $Y =-1$ \\\hline
   n_{+}&The number of patients experience toxicity \\\hline
   n_{-}&The number of patients do not experience toxicity \\\hline
   Z_{i+}&The number of patient has a major allele for $i$th SNP given that patient experience toxicity \\\hline
   Z_{i-}& \makecell{The number of patient has a minor allele for $i$th SNP given that patient do not experience toxicity} \\\hline}
    \hline
    \caption{Summary of notations}
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have compiled your code. Since there are some mistakes such as missing $ signs, I just continued in batch mode. However, the result was fine, a table at the top of page. Hence I guess that your problem has to do with the heading and/or the text which your image shows, but which is not contained in your LaTeX code.

Comment: Do you actually use the `article` class in your real document? Because you don't have the table in a floating environment, and there isn't room in the page for the whole table, you are bound to get extra whitespace somewhere. That the whitespace occurs between the section and the paragraph could indicate that you're using a class where `\flushbottom` is active, meaning that the content of each page is stretched to fill the text area. `article` doesn't do that by default, while for example `book` does.

Comment: the code posted will give multiple errors about mis-use of math, after a Tex error you shouldn't even look at the pdf  file, TeX's recovery if you scroll past an error is just designed to enable more error checking it is not designed to make sensible typeset output.